# Dynamic connection for each user nodejs

Tags: node.js

Have created a web application with nodeJs, I have a situation now

consider a table with the columns
username, password, ip addresses, database name, dbusername, dbpassword etc...

1. The login from the web app should connect to this table and authenticate the user.
2. While authenticating the db detail columns are read for that user.
3. And after successful login the nodejs connection should use this loaded db (only for this user).
4. Now, Open one more instance of the app and login with different user, this time the node should use the db for this user (might be same / different).

Being a single threaded model is it possible  to have dynamic connection for each user in nodeJS?
Does opening and closing connections (with different db config)  work well in this case?

Thanks,
Saran

Comment: It should work fine, yes.

Comment: Solved this using PoolCluster.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. express-session comes with functionalities that manages sessions. https://github.com/expressjs/session
2. passport.js is a very good solution for authentication in node.js. http://passportjs.org/

There are many tutorials out there for passport.js and session management.

For example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Also sessions have nothing to do with single-threaded model. Even if you are multiple threaded you don't keep the connection up for each user after sending them the page. Cookies are used to identify who is visiting the site. Node.js have native functions that can also launch a cluster of Node.js processes to take advantage of the multi-core systems. In that case session can still be managed even across processes by using things like redis.

About clusters: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html